# PatternSyntaxException when trying to validate Latin characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to validate some input where just latin letters are allowed. For that I am using the next regex:

```
public boolean isValidInput(String inputText) {
    return inputText != null && Pattern.matches("\\p{IsLatin}+", inputText);
}
```

But when I run it I get a `PatternSyntaxException`:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test, PID: 27758
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
\p{IsLatin}+
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:424)
    ...
```

I am using Java 8 and compiling with Android SDK 27. I have tested it in three devices with Android 6, 7 and 8 and same result.

I have tried to run the same code in an [standalone Java 8 program](http://tpcg.io/PE1ruJ) and it works fine.
The [Android regex doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) page does not say anything that `\p{IsLatin}` is not supported.

> Classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties
>   `\p{IsLatin}` A Latin script character (script)

Any idea?

Comment: Interesting, you could try `\\p{L}` (letter) instead of `\\p{IsL}` (is latin). Maybe `"(?u)\\p{IsLatin}+"`.

Comment: `\p{Latin}` works! Thanks you so much Joop :) ..I've spent one day trying to make it work..

Answer (score 6):

I've just noticed this line in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (thanks @Joop for pointing it out):

> Categories may be specified with the optional prefix Is: Both \p{L}
>   and \p{IsL} denote the category of Unicode letters.

It seems that `\p{IsLatin}` is just an alias of `\p{Latin}`. Both work in native Java, but just `\p{Latin}` **works for Android** (although Android Studio highlights it red and warns you that is an "Unknown character category").

So now my validation method looks like:

```
public boolean isLatinInput(String inputText) {
    return inputText != null && Pattern.matches("\\p{Latin}+", inputText);
}
```

Comment: Well, [category may not mean what you think it does](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html#categories), and [\p{Latin} may not work on all Java versions](https://github.com/pemistahl/lingua/issues/3). Rather an unfortunate situation. I wish the android developers would fix this.